# Java NAL to H264

Tags: java, h.264, rtp

Did anybody ever use a good open source Java lib that would allow NAL > H264 conversion ?

I've seen lots of libs, but most of them incomplete or very hard to use (no documentation etc.).

What I want is to pass the NAL payload and get the actual H.264 raw video. The next step would be putting this into a MP4 container.

Answer (score 2):

From the discussion in the comments I rephrase your question and split it into two:

### I want to extract NAL units from H264 RTP packets in pure java and dump them into an Annex B H264 file.

How do I do that? Is there a library?

The payload of these packets is specified in [RFC3984](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt).

I don't know any Java library that performs this out of the box. But implementation is fairly simple as long as the packaging type is not interleaved:

RFC3984 allows three packaging type

- Single NAL unit mode
- Non-interleaved mode
- Interleaved mode

as long as your packet source is sending in single NAL unit mode or non-interleaved mode you can extract the NAL units without any further processing from the packets and dump them to disk with 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01 as divider between them.

If the packaging type is interleaved you need to put a lot more work into that since than you will have to look into the NALs and re-order them to be in decoding order.

### I mux raw Annex B H264 files into an MP4 container in pure Java

You can you use my [mp4parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) project to generate a MP4 from the Annex B format. Have a look at the [H264Example](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/muxformats/H264Example.java) - that should give you an idea on how to use it.

Comment: I am looking forward to extracting the raw H264 from RTP payload. Can mp4parser help on that ? Or are you aware of other tools that would ?

Comment: Nope the mp4parser won't help you with that. It may only help to create MP4 from a raw H264 stream. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt describes how H264 Nals are packaged in RTP messages. Extracting them should not be a problem. A problem could arise if they would need reordering but I'm not sure if it is needed

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I'd like to improve my posting - give me a chance. I think that I provided valuable information to 'Display Name' and yes - my tool could help him. Is advertising my lib the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have just upvoted you, don't know who/why did downvote you. Are you aware of any lib that does handle NAL to H.264 conversion ?

Comment: So if you talk about NAL to H.264 conversion you are actually talking about extracting NAL units from RTP payload?

Comment: Yes. Extracting NAL and appending the right NAL content (and not only, see NAL prefix) in order to obtain a valid H.264 raw stream that can later be used by mp4parser to generate a MP4 file.

Comment: Extracting H.264 NAL units from an RTP stream is fairly trivial. See `RFC 3984` for the H.264 RTP Payload specification.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found in JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ) samples:

```
public class AVCMP4Mux {
    private static AvcCBox avcC;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Syntax: <in.264> <out.mp4>\n" + "\tWhere:\n"
                    + "\t-q\tLook for stream parameters only in the beginning of stream");
            return;
        }

        File in = new File(args[0]);
        File out = new File(args[1]);

        SeekableByteChannel file = writableFileChannel(out);
        MP4Muxer muxer = new MP4Muxer(file);
        CompressedTrack track = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

        mux(track, in);

        muxer.writeHeader();

        file.close();
    }

    private static void mux(CompressedTrack track, File f) throws IOException {
        MappedH264ES es = new MappedH264ES(NIOUtils.map(f));

        ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        Packet frame = null;
        while ((frame = es.nextFrame()) != null) {
            ByteBuffer wrap = frame.getData().duplicate();
            H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(wrap, spsList, ppsList);
            MP4Packet pkt = new MP4Packet(new Packet(frame, wrap), frame.getPts(), 0);
            System.out.println(pkt.getFrameNo());
            track.addFrame(pkt);
        }
        addSampleEntry(track, es.getSps(), es.getPps());
    }

    private static void addSampleEntry(CompressedTrack track, SeqParameterSet[] spss, PictureParameterSet[] ppss) {
        SeqParameterSet sps = spss[0];
        Size size = new Size((sps.pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 + 1) << 4, getPicHeightInMbs(sps) << 4);

        SampleEntry se = MP4Muxer.videoSampleEntry("avc1", size, "JCodec");

        avcC = new AvcCBox(sps.profile_idc, 0, sps.level_idc, write(spss), write(ppss));
        se.add(avcC);
        track.addSampleEntry(se);
    }

    private static List<ByteBuffer> write(PictureParameterSet[] ppss) {
        List<ByteBuffer> result = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        for (PictureParameterSet pps : ppss) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            pps.write(buf);
            buf.flip();
            result.add(buf);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<ByteBuffer> write(SeqParameterSet[] spss) {
        List<ByteBuffer> result = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        for (SeqParameterSet sps : spss) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            sps.write(buf);
            buf.flip();
            result.add(buf);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I took it from here: https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/samples/main/java/org/jcodec/samples/mux/AVCMP4Mux.java